# Animated App Icon for macOS

Tags: macos

I have a question regarding macOS app icons. I've seen a number of animated icons before, but never really paid close attention to what was going on / how they were doing it. I was just wondering if there was any way to create an animated app icon that animates in the dock.

For example: [image: http://imgur.com/a/opXCr]

Is it possible to do this via an animated media file, or even programatically?

Answer (score 2):

Years past, there is a new package called [`DSFDockTile`](https://github.com/dagronf/DSFDockTile).

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a brief dock icon animation, you might loop the following code via a timer. (Untested Obj-C).

```
NSDockTile *dockTile=[[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile];
NSImageView *dockImageView=[[NSImageView alloc] init];
NSImage *iconImage=[NSImage imageNamed: ##MY_IMAGE_FRAME##];
[dockImageView setImage: iconImage];
[dockTile setContentView: dockImageView];
[dockTile display];
```